# i want to get rid of an entire package?

Tags: permissions, reinstall, wireshark

So I installed Wireshark just now and I said no to the super user thing(in hindsight I have literally no idea why), and when I tried to run it it said it didn't have permission, then gave me some instructions. I did the instructions, that didn't work, then I deleted and reinstalled it. I guess I just deleted the name but not the files? so I want to get rid of all the files for it, then install again. I used purge if that helps.

Comment: If you used `apt purge`, the program and all files related to it will be deleted.

Comment: If you installed it using `sudo apt install` yes you can remove with `sudo apt remove` (or `sudo apt purge` to also remove config files *as Eate already stated*), however if you installed a snap (using snap install) the command is `snap remove` ; if you installed via source .... - ie. the reverse of the method used to install it which you didn't specify.